# How do you tell when tab name is changed?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have this script as my background.js:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
    alert(tab.title);
});
```

But that doesnt fire when just the tab's name is changed, only when it's reloaded/visit new page.

Is there a way to make it so it will fire when the tab name is updated also?

Answer (score 0):

With standard Chrome.* API it is not possible to trace such tab name changes.

## Work Around

Use a content script to track DOM Changes and use your functional Logic in the callback

### Sample code

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified",function (){ 
    alert("changed.."); 
});
```